# How to insert data to database using seeder in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with seeder. My data not insert to the database. The table `customers` are created but data not insert to database. Below I show me code. I use
`php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`
Migration

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('first_name', 20);
            $table->string('last_name', 30);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('phone_number')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Model

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'phone_number'
    ];
}
```

Factory

```
class CustomerFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'first_name'   => fake()->firstName(),
            'last_name'    => fake()->lastName(),
            'email'        => fake()->unique()->safeEmail(),
            'phone_number' => fake()->unique()->phoneNumber()
        ];
    }
}
```

Seeder

```
class CustomersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Customer::factory(20)->create();
    }
}
```

Now show me error

```js
 at C:\laragon\www\zadanie-rekrutacyjne\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1307
    1303▕      * @return string
    1304▕      */
    1305▕     public function getAlias($abstract)
    1306▕     {
  ➜ 1307▕         return isset($this->aliases[$abstract])
    1308▕                     ? $this->getAlias($this->aliases[$abstract])
    1309▕                     : $abstract;
    1310▕     }
    1311▕

  1   C:\laragon\www\zadanie-rekrutacyjne\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:843
      Illuminate\Container\Container::getAlias(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection))

  2   C:\laragon\www\zadanie-rekrutacyjne\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Seeder.php:129
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::make(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection))
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the `DatabaseSeeder class`, you have to call the method to execute additional seed classes.

```
/**
 * Run the database seeders.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $this->call([
        CustomersTableSeeder::class,
       
    ]);
}
```

As per the official doc:

> Within the DatabaseSeeder class, you may use the call method to
> execute additional seed classes. Using the call method allows you to
> break up your database seeding into multiple files so that no single
> seeder class becomes too large. The call method accepts an array of
> seeder classes that should be executed:

Ref: [Calling Additional Seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/seeding#calling-additional-seeders)

Comment: That's work, now insert data to database but showe me error `TypeError 
 Illegal offset type in isset or empty` how can I fix that ?

Comment: @perh23 as per your question i cant tell where exactly that error throws .better you can debug and mention which  line it throwing error

Comment: I modify my post and show what exacty is error

Comment: @perh23.not sure why that erorr throwing but your question code woks fine since i have tested here